# XAMPP phpmyadmin error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed XAMPP. When I was browsing http://localhost/phpmyadmin then I found below error. Can anyone say what is the solution ??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

These messages should be clear. The first one gives a link that will help you solve the situation, in order to have a full-features phpMyAdmin. The second one advises about a security hole in your MySQL Server and tells you how to fix it.